# Find If foreign_key Existes In Active Record Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

My app has Users, Courses, and Lessons. I'm trying to calculate how many Lessons a User has completed in a given Course. I've created a join table called `LessonCompletion`, but I'm having trouble with the query. Here are the relevant models:

/app/models/user.rb:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :enrollments
  has_many :courses, through: :enrollments

  has_many :lesson_completions
  has_many :lessons, through: :lesson_completions
end
```

/app/models/courses.rb:

```
class Course < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :lessons
  has_many :enrollments
  has_many :users, through: :enrollments
end
```

/app/models/lesson.rb:

```
class Lesson < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :course
end
```

/app/models/lesson_completion.rb:

```
class LessonCompletion < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :lesson
  belongs_to :user
end
```

If I call `current_user.lesson_completions` I get:

```
[#<LessonCompletion:0x00007feb482ba4e0
  id: 1,
  lesson_id: 5,
  user_id: 1,
  ...>]
```

If I call `@course.lessons` get:

```
[#<Lesson:0x00007feb482c1920
  id: 5,
  course_id: 2,
  ...>,
 #<Lesson:0x00007feb482a8790
  id: 6,
  course_id: 2,
  ...>]
```

I've tried various combinations of `.where` and `.join`, but in every case I get "Object doesn't support #inspect" or "method_missing" or "Unsupported argument type".

How can I compare the `lesson_id`s from `current_user.lesson_completions` with the `id`s in `@course.lessons`?

Comment: Did you try includes method? Will have something like: current_user.lessons.includes(:lesson_completions), but may be required to do few adjustments your modeling.

Comment: That returns `Object doesn't support #inspect`. I don't know how to adjust it to get a valid return.